# Stream video to TV over HDMI in background?

Tags: streaming

I have a powerful computer running Linux (Debian) desktop. I use it for work as well as for night-time computations. So it's running 24x7. I also have non-smart TV with HDMI input and dedicated Pioneer receiver for sound. What I want is to use my computer as a media server. I do not want to connect TV as a second monitor because it will interfere with my work. I want some application that will run in background, stream content directly to HDMI and digital audio and be operated by some client. I have looked at the Kodi but didn't find out how to run it in background and how to dedicate HDMI port to it. I have looked at Plex but it requires Plex Client App on output device. I could buy something like Chromecast as a last resort but I will be not able to connect my audio receiver then.

Are there any options to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 2):

The way you do this *is* to connect the TV as a second monitor, but configure it as a separate X screen so it's no part of your main desktop (and therefore doesn't interfere with your work). Then you can run any kind of application(s) you like on the second X screen, streaming or whatever.

I doing this on my system with an Intel card, BTW. Here's the relevant part of my `xorg.conf`:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier "intel0"
    Driver "intel"
    Option "AccelMethod" "sna"
    Option "ZaphodHeads" "VGA1,HDMI1,DP1"
    Screen 0
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "intel1"
    Driver "intel"
    Option "AccelMethod" "sna"
    Option "ZaphodHeads" "HDMI3"
    Screen 1
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "screen0"
    Device "intel0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "screen1"
    Device "intel1"
EndSection
```

What you need to do may vary according to your graphics card (which you didn't tell us about), and you will have to vary the output names. I think I head to use the `sna` to work around some issue with the video overlay that may no longer be relevant.

First screen is `:0`, you need to start any application for the second screen with `-display :1` or whatever variation of the commandline switch the application uses.

Comment: I have an integrated Intel video on Asus Z170 Pro motherboard with DisplayPort connected to my monitor and HDMI port that I want to connect to TV. I've got your idea, thanks! I'll try it as soon as I will manage to split video outputs so they are independent (currently there is some problem with the driver, it does not support splitting, only mirroring).